# Change font of mathematics numbers

Tags: fonts

I have a document in which the text is typeset in Garamond. The mathematics symbols are not typeset in Garamod, which is the way I like it. However, I would like the numbers 0...9 to be typeset in Garamond. How do I achieve this?

EDIT: I am emphasizing that I do not want all my mathematics in Garamond, only the digits 0...9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this (replace phv by the name of your font):

```
\documentclass{article}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{phv}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{T1}{phv}{bx}{n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\begin{document}
abc

$a=123$

\mathversion{bold}

$a=345$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The font of single characters or symbols may be changed by `\DeclareMathSymbol`:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{garamond}{T1}{pad}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathord}{garamond}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathord}{garamond}{`2}
...
```

For complete switching to Garamond, you could use [`mathdesign`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign) with `garamond` option:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
% In the case of another commercial Garamond font like `pad` add afterwards:
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{pad}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pad}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I am using a proprietary Garamond from my university which is invoked by `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pad}`.

Comment: Specify that after loading mathdesign. I extended my answer.

Comment: That still gives me an error. `(file 
ugmmi8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading`

Comment: @Ben: `ugmmi8a.pfb` belongs to the [urw-garamond package](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/urw-garamond), you need to install that for mathdesign-garamond, even if you later switch to `pad`.

Comment: OK, but that did not give me the desired result, for one, the characters 0...9 are now typeset in the new Garamond, not 'pad'. Worse, all mathematics symbols are now typeset in Garamond.

Comment: @Ben: Ok, I'll add code for only changing the numbers.