# Oldstyle numbers with Charter font

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums

I'm using the Charter font using the following package:

```
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
```

I want to have oldstyle (lowercase) numbers in conjunction with this package. I've seen this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/utilizing-oldstyle-figures-without-resorting-to-oldstylenums) but it refers to CM and palatino only. Any way of getting oldstyle numbering (throughout the document) with Charter font?

Comment: Does charter have oldstyle numbers? I don't see any given in the [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/charter/).

Comment: That's the question :)  ... Do I simply give up on the font or the oldstyle figure or is there a way to have them both.

Comment: There is no old-style numbers in Bitstream Charter fonts. You may temporarily change to another font for the numbers.

Comment: Leo Liu. That sounds like a plan but how do I change *all* numbers to another font?

Comment: @recluze you can give a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/change-font-of-mathematics-numbers

Comment: @recluze: No. I meant that you can just redefine `\oldstylenums` to change to a font you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is No. `LaTeX`defines `\oldstylenums`

```
\def\oldstylenums#1{%
   \begingroup
    \spaceskip\fontdimen\tw@\font
    \usefont{OML}{\rmdefault}{\f@series}{it}%
    \mathgroup\symletters #1%
   \endgroup
}
```

When a font contains old style numbers, like `fourier`, you find in the package fourier.sty  an option :  `oldstyle`.

```
\DeclareOption{oldstyle}{\def\textfamilyextension{j}%
\def\mathfamilyextension{x}\poormanfalse}
```

with

```
\newcommand*{\oldstyle}{\fontfamily{futj}\selectfont}
```

but  in `charter.sty` there nothing about oldstyle. This is not encouraging

Answer (score 4):

read the documentation `texdoc mathdesign` there you'll find a topic "oldstyle figures"

With a faked font, because charter scmall caps are not free:

[image]

Comment: Well, it has a section which says '... oldstyle figures', but there is no mention at all of anything in the text.

Comment: sure, it is: "Now use the mathdesign package with the option expert. Small caps and oldstyle figure are available with the command `\textsc{...}`."

Comment: Okay, I'd missed that one line. It seems very odd, however, to say that old style figures appear in `\textsc`: that's clearly an abuse (and pretty useless for the normal use case of having lower case figures in body text).

Comment: There is : The following options are available:
expert if the corresponding postscript font are available on your system, this option activates them. The question now becomes : Is the corresponding font is available?

Comment: no, that is the default for a lot of TYPE 1 fonts, combining small caps and old style numbers ... One can choose any _existing_ pfb file and copy it to `bchrc8a.pfb` and the oldstyle feature works. Modifying the style file is also possible.