# How to use \MakeUppercase in combination with the bm package in LaTeX 2022-11-01

Tags: pdftex, bugs, bm, uppercase

I am trying to submit LaTeX sources to arXiv and I ran into some issues.
My project lives in overleaf where I am using TeX Live 2021 and everything compiles without any errors or warnings (except from overfull or underfull boxes).
However, when I tried to process the source files on arXiv, the `\MakeUppercase` leads to a compilation error.

I was able to replicate the error *locally* using the following snippet, suggesting that the combination of the `bm` package and the `\MakeUppercase` is the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
Test plain: $\bm{x}$.

%replacing \bm by \boldsymbol resolves the issue
Test upper: $\bm{\MakeUppercase{x}}$.
\end{document}
```

However, I was unable to replicate this issue inside overleaf (trying both TeX Live 2022 and 2023).
After some more digging, I figured out that my TeX Live (2023) distribution uses LaTeX2e 2022-11-01, whereas overleaf uses 2022-06-01.
Also, arXiv seems to be using 2022-11-01.

While looking around, I noticed there have been some changes to `\MakeUppercase` that caused [issues](https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/issues/29) with the `microtype` package.
Furthermore, I found this [Github issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/987) on issues with the Greek alphabet.
I am not sure if these issues are related, but they definitely seem relevant.

[This comment](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/987#issuecomment-1413564706) in the Github issue seems to suggest that it is better/easier to fix the code than to create a workaround.
However, (to the best of my knowledge) I cannot change the LaTeX version on the arXiv servers.
Therefore, it seems like I will need some sort of workaround after all.

One solution I could think of would be to replace `\usepackage{bm}` by something like `\let\bm\boldsymbol`, but I'm unsure whether this would have any undesired effects to the typesetting.
Is this a reasonable solution, or are there other options I should consider to upload my project to arXiv?

More generally, I would also be interested to understand why `\MakeUppercase` causes this many issues recently.
E.g. Is there a list of packages that are known to have issues with `\MakeUppercase` and is there a more general solution?

---

**update**: On version 2022-11-01 patch level 1, `\MakeUppercase` also fails with `\boldsymbol` with the following error(s):

```
/home/hoedt/Downloads/tmp/test.tex:10: Undefined control sequence.
\MakeUppercase    [#1]#2->\let \kernel@saved@oe 
                                                \oe \let \oe \OE \@@text@cas...
l.10 Test upper: $\boldsymbol{\MakeUppercase{x}}
                                                $.
/home/hoedt/Downloads/tmp/test.tex:10: Undefined control sequence.
\MakeUppercase    ...#2}\let \oe \kernel@saved@oe 
                                                  
l.10 Test upper: $\boldsymbol{\MakeUppercase{x}}
                                                $.
/home/hoedt/Downloads/tmp/test.tex:10: Extra }, or forgotten $.
\bm@command ...\space \@spaces \@spaces \@spaces }
                                                  {LaTeX Warning: Command \p...
l.10 Test upper: $\boldsymbol{\MakeUppercase{x}}
                                                $.
```

Comment: it looks very odd to use \MakeUppercase in math. Why don't you simply type `\bm{X}`??

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have defined commands to typeset vectors and matrices as in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584583), so this "simple" solution might break some things and/or requires me to go through the entire document to fix possible typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty nice workaround has been provided by egreg in an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/707122/1) to another question of mine.

It is possible to define a new command `\ToUppercase` using the LaTeX3 coding language:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \ToUppercase \text_uppercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This command does not cause issues when used with `\boldsymbol` or `\bm` and allows me to compile my documents.
I am not sure if there are (subtle) differences to `\MakeUppercase`, but it seems to work well enough for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Updates to how case changing works have been made to support UTF-8 and `babel`/`polyglossia`. This has been an iterative process as it could not be done in one place in one step. The latest release of LaTeX (2023-11-01) supported by up-to-date `expl3` uses an improved approach which does not require `\kernel@saved@oe`: rather it retains the 'traditional' grouping inside `\MakeUppercase`. As such, the best advice here is to update to current LaTeX or to use the `latexrelease` mechanism to patch an older kernel to achieve the same effect.

Comment: As noted by Ulrike, case changing for maths is normally not a great plan ...

Comment: I tried using `\RequirePackage[2023-11-01]{latexrelease}` before `\documentclass` (as well as some other, older dates), but it seems to do nothing. I also learned that my OS only updates TeX Live on a yearly basis (currently 2023). The latest system update installed a new release of the package, but reverting did not resolve anything. This makes things really weird, because this used to compile just fine. Is there any other package outside of TeX Live that could be interfering here? Where should `\kernel@saved@oe` be defined?

Comment: Have you got the latest version of `latexrelease`? It won't be included in an older TeX distribution, so you've have to have downloaded it yourself.

Comment: But really, we are back with case changing does not belong in math mode, as case in maths is important ...